# Footer Background image shrinks when changing width of window

Tags: html, css

I have a footer i created for a website, but for some reason when i change the width of the window the background image seems to just disappear throughout the right side as i'm shrinking the width of the window.

The footer is supposed to stretch 100% accross the bottom of the screen and does so until i start shrinking the width of the window to a certain point.

You can see an example of my issue [Here](http://syndicatebox.com/footerissue/)

Any ideas how to fix this? I am totally stumped. Maybe i did something wrong with width?

[image: Example]

Comment: I just took out a peace of this code and put it in the link as an example.

Answer (score 1):

The width of `#footer` is set to `auto`, and the content within (`#content-wrapper`) has a fixed width.

This is causing the horizontal bars to appear.

To solve this, you can set `overflow:hidden` to the parent div (`#footer`).

Try this:

```
#footer {
    background-image: url("images/footer-bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 451px;
    margin: auto 0;
    width: 100%;

    overflow: hidden; //What you're looking for.
}
```

If you also want the inner div (`#content-wrapper`) to dynamically resize itself, use a percentage, instead of a pixel dimension for width:

```
#footer #content-wrapper {
    height: 451px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 83%;
}
```

Comment: That kinda works but if there is content there it wont let me scroll to the right for some reason.

Comment: I will definitely need it to be a certain width, just for some reason its not letting me scroll to the left side of the footer content. It works though but not to that extent!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have check to your demo page you have define your footer `width 1265px`  and now

than your define min width your `html` or `body` as like this

```
body, html {
    min-width: 1265px;
}
```

because your max width is 1265 define to your footer so that **you define** `same width` your `body or html`